# How to convert a Timestamp to Unix Epoch time using Bash

Tags: bash, timestamps

I have a timestamp similar to this: `2022-11-09T14:41:15.555641007Z`

I would like to convert this to Unix epoch time in seconds like this: `1668005090`

How can I achieve this using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)?

Comment: Are you using a Linux-based distribution with GNU tools, or some other Linux/UNIX?

Answer (score 3):

Like this (assuming the GNU or ast-open implementation of `date`):

```
$ date -d '2022-11-09T14:41:15.555641007Z' +%s
1668004875
```

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, assuming the input is known to be in UTC:

```
% t='2022-11-09T14:41:15.555641007Z';
% date -j -f "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" "${t%.*}+0000" +%s                          
1668004875
```

The `${t%.*}+0000` removes the nanoseconds and the `Z` marker, and adds `+0000` as the time zone marker, since that's what `%z` expects.

If it's not in UTC, you'll need to turn it into a format like `2022-11-09T14:41:15+hhmm` beforehand and then use `date -j -f "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" "$t" +%s` on it.

The options for the [FreeBSD version of `date`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=date&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD+13.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) look similar, so this might work there, too.